# Cannot focus lens in manual or AF. Nikon DX AF-S 55-300mm lens

Tags: nikon-d5300

I am having trouble focusing my Nikon DX AF-S 55-300mm VR lens with my Nikon D5300 camera.
It will not focus or take pictures at all, in AF or manual. The body works with other lens, it used to work a few days ago, but not amymore.

It will not focus in either manual or AF, you can here the motors working and the lens moves in AF but no focus, just a blur
I have looked at settings, but i am no expert... far from.
any help would be appriciated.
Many thanks
Gary

Comment: Before we go any further, check the A/M switch on the side isn't set to M.

Comment: I have checked both. will not focus in either manual or AF, you can here the motors working and the lens moves in AF but no focus, just a blur

Comment: Then I'd guess your next port of call will be a repair shop. You should add that salient information to your actual question, as it aids diagnosis.

Comment: Have added extra info. thanks for your help